# Class not found Exception in AWS Java Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

this is the exception we get

```
Exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.A.B.C.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

all the source is in the root directory and 
the lib in the lib directory

this works when built from local machine but not from Jenkins

in both jenkins and on local mac we used Gradle to compile,
the Gradle zip build the zip artifact

to be more specific I followed whats here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'jars', include: '*.jar')
}

task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

seems which is not enough we also need to use chmod

Comment: Needs more info, what's the command used locally to build the jar? What's the command in Jenkins? What's the diff between those two jars? Does the exception happen locally?

Comment: So the problem is that Jenkins build produces the artefact that differs from the one produced by local build. Look into your Jenkins build and spot the difference. There is nothing specific to AWS in this question.

Comment: in both jenkins and on local mac we used gradle to compile

the gradle zip command to build the artifact

Comment: @nickolay.laptev 
I found the root cause the root folder of the zip does not have read permissions for all so was throwing not found exception

I expected when I upload the zip to AWS Lambda it would handle the permissions on those files (considering there is no use of having a file like that)

Answer (score 0):

The root folder did not have read permission for everyone. To fix the problem,i I had to call `chmod` to set the permissions properly before the zip task.